# django : concatenate 2 queries or special order?

Tags: python, django, concatenation

I have to make such query :

```
similar_brokers_ = Profile.objects.filter(Q(tp=broker.tp) |  Q(md=broker.md)).exclude(Q(id=broker.id))[:4]
```

i need to get 4 similar brokers, which have the same `tp` field or `md` field

so this query does it, but i need brokers with the same `tp` field go first, after them should go brokers with the same `md` field.

how can i do it better?

for example :

```
broker1  with tp=1, md=100
broker2  with tp=2, md=100
broker3  with tp=1, md=99
```

get brokers similat to `broker1` :
first should go `broker3` (with `tp`=1) and after `broker2` (with `md`=100)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with `order_by('tp', 'md')` ? See docs for [order_by](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by)

Comment: but if broker1 has tp=2, and other brokers with tp=1 with the same md as broker1 will be first, cause 1 < 2 you know, am i right ?

Comment: Can you show 0. a set of data and 1. the resulting list you want.